# UIBarButtonItem, set exclusive touch

Tags: xcode, touch, uibarbuttonitem

Is there a way to make `UIBarButtonItem` exclusive touch? At the moment you can select multiple at the same time and it keeps crashing my application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Slightly easier method than subclassing the navbar but the same idea;

```
for(UIView *temp in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews)
{
    [temp setExclusiveTouch:YES];
}
```

Put this just after you add your bar button items.

Answer (score 8):

I managed this problem by subclassing UINavigationBar and overriding layoutSubviews method. Something like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        view.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Dredging up the past I apologise. I stumbled into this and hoped there was a better way than looping through subviews.

I found that the following makes the UIBarButtonItems exclusive:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setExclusiveTouch:YES];
```

iOS7 may have made exclusive touch inherited.

Comment: not working in iOS15

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7 it wasn't working. I have used this method to try fix it.

```
for(UIView *temp in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews){
    [temp setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    for(UIView *temp2 in temp.subviews){
        [temp2 setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

for me, I used a `UIButton`, setting its isExclusiveTouch to true, to initialize the `UIBarButtonItem`.

```
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
button.setTitle("foo", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
button.isExclusiveTouch = true

let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

Answer (score -1):

This does not work for UIBarButtonItem created using initWithTitle

Comment: what doesn't work? shouldn't this be a comment on someone else's post?