# PushViewController in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios7

There are around 6-7 `UIButtons` on a `UINavigationController's` view.
All buttons push a new view on the `UINavigationController`.

Here is my problem,

iOS 7:

**Problem:** if I tap 2 buttons simultaneously, application is loading a new view but, when I push back button, It is crashing the application.

**Reason:** It is pushing 2 views on the stack.

For iOS 6 it is working fine, is there any way we can restrict tapping 2 buttons simultaneously for iOS 7?

Comment: It is not the issue of iOS 7. Even in iOS 6 If you press two button simultaneously will give same result. Youn need to set Exclusive property to YES of UIButton.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre, yes you are right, but in iOS 6 if you touch both buttons one action of the two will be invoked. Whereas in iOS 7 both actions are invoking.

Comment: i've the same issue. Now i set all my button with exclusivetouch but if i press back buttons and another button the app crash

Comment: @digitalPad , I solved it by creating a new class(inherited by UIButton) and then used a method 'initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)inCoder' (which allows you to set properties of button programatically), Than all you need to do is to change custom class name (in inspector of button) in nib file( or files where you created button).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With one of the answers provided here, I modified it for my whole application. I created a new class which inherits UIButton class and in that class added a method

```
 - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)inCoder{
       self = [super initWithCoder:inCoder];
       if (self) {
           //do custom
           [self setExclusiveTouch:YES];
       }
       return self;
 }
```

after that I used this class instead UIButton.

**Benifit:** no need to make an outlet.

Answer (score 1):

Make Outlets do those buttons and then:

```
[yourButton setExclusiveTouch:YES];
```

Comment: Your piece of code works for me (Modified a little, [present in answers below link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217366/pushviewcontroller-in-ios-7/20218421#20218421)). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I managed this problem by subclassing UINavigationBar and overriding layoutSubviews method. Something like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        view.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    }
}
```

original answer [UIBarButtonItem, set exclusive touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410379/uibarbuttonitem-set-exclusive-touch)